# how to make a overflow popup inside div show above without overflow?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
<div> // parent div with display flex and no wrap
    <div> // div 1 which has popup inside with overflow
    </div>
    <div> // div 2
    </div>
    <div> // div 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to make the popup show above without overflowing, cant resize the div 1 or the popup, Tried with `position: absolute` or `z-index`, None worked

Added the sample jsfiddle link below. Please help

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wolf07/y1jfgwx7/14/)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Just click the `[<>]`  button in the editor

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean with "above" without overflowing?

If you want to toggle the div and show it above, this will work better than your current code where you have to click twice

```js
const pop = document.querySelector(".popup")
const myFunction = () => pop.hidden = !pop.hidden;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.inbox-filter {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e7f2;
  background: #f9fbfe;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  flex: 0 0 380px;
}

.inbox-grid {
  flex: 0 0 380px;
  min-width: 330px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #e8edf7;
}

.inbox-msg-body {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.popup {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container" style="min-height: auto">
  <div class="inbox-filter">
    <h4>Date Range</h4>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
       Date Range
    </button>
    <div class="popup" hidden>
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inbox-grid">

  </div>
  <div class="inbox-msg-body">

  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to show the popup inside

```js
const pop = document.querySelector(".popup");
pop.closest("div.inbox-filter").style.overflow = "hidden";
const myFunction = () => pop.hidden = !pop.hidden;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.inbox-filter {
  height: calc(100vh - 44px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e7f2;
  background: #f9fbfe;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  flex: 0 0 380px;
}

.inbox-grid {
  flex: 0 0 380px;
  min-width: 330px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #e8edf7;
}

.inbox-msg-body {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 550px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.popup {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container" style="min-height: auto">
  <div class="inbox-filter">
    <h4>Date Range</h4>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
       Date Range
    </button>
    <div class="popup" hidden>
      Hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inbox-grid">

  </div>
  <div class="inbox-msg-body">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first answer is what I need. But sadly its not working, Its not making the popup above the div, it still make the div scroll horizontally

Comment: The div is not scrolling, it is the page. You can wrap the put div in a 100% wide container and set that to overflow-y none